# Gradle build fails with "org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/FileRepositoryBuilder has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java"

Tags: gradle, java-8

Starting from today I cannot build my project anymore. There are no changes in it.
Looks like some Gradle dependency is recompiled with Java 11.
I'm using Java 8 and Gradle 4.10.

**org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/FileRepositoryBuilder has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0**

Does anyone have the same problem?

```
    ./gradlew --version
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Gradle 4.10.3
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Build time:   2018-12-05 00:50:54 UTC
    Revision:     e76905e3a1034e6f724566aeb985621347ff43bc
    
    Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
    Kotlin:       1.2.61
    Groovy:       2.4.15
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
    JVM:          1.8.0_292 (Private Build 25.292-b10)
    OS:           Linux 4.15.0-142-generic amd64
```

```
    echo $JAVA_HOME
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

```
./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/FileRepositoryBuilder has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Comment: How about the dependency of your project?

Comment: Do the dependencies matter when even the "clean" is not working?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. Gradle plug-in 'id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "4.1.0"'.

Comment: Got the same problem yesterday by using a different git-gradle-plugin com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've changed the version of Gradle plug-in **org.ajoberstar.grgit** in build.gradle and it is working. The version before was 4.1.0. Now: **4.1.1**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "4.1.1"
}
```